# JQuery .animate() in plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I create this plugin but when i use it on 2 different selectors: `$('.1').Breath()` and `$('.2').Breath()` it's not workin fine and when i stop it on one of selectors:`$('.1').BreathStop()` animate of all selectors going to stop.
I don't know what is the problem

```
(function($) {
  var breathing;
  $.fn.Breath = function() {

    var options = $.extend({
      minOpacity: 0,
      maxOpacity: 1,
      BreathIn  : 1000,
      BreathOut : 3000
    }, arguments[0]);

    return this.each(function() {
      breathing = true;
      var obj = $(this);
      function breath() {
        if(stop()) return;
        obj.stop().animate({
          opacity: options.minOpacity
        }, options.BreathOut, function() {
          if(stop()) return;
          obj.stop().animate({
            opacity: options.maxOpacity
          }, options.BreathIn, function() {
            if(stop()) return;
            obj.stop();
            breath();
          });
        });
      }

      breath();

      function stop() {
        if(!breathing)
          obj.stop().css({opacity: 1});
        return !breathing;
      }
    });
  }

  $.fn.BreathStop = function() {
    breathing = false;
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Variable `breathing` is common for all elements.

Comment: How can i make it local ? it's really important to `BreathStop()` make it stop how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "localize" your `breathing` variable. Currently it is common for all the elements using your plugin.

The easiest way that comes to my mind is using element's `data`:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.Breath = function() {

        var options = $.extend({
            minOpacity: 0,
            maxOpacity: 1,
            BreathIn: 1000,
            BreathOut: 3000
        }, arguments[0]);
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            obj.data("breathing", true);

            function breath() {
                if (stop()) return;
                obj.stop().animate({
                    opacity: options.minOpacity
                }, options.BreathOut, function() {
                    if (stop()) return;
                    obj.stop().animate({
                        opacity: options.maxOpacity
                    }, options.BreathIn, function() {
                        if (stop()) return;
                        obj.stop();
                        breath();
                    });
                });
            }
            breath();

            function stop() {
                if (!obj.data("breathing")) obj.stop().css({
                    opacity: 1
                });
                return !obj.data("breathing");
            }
        });
    }
    $.fn.BreathStop = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).data("breathing", false);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```